# Delete records with pagination rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination

I have index page(table) with pagination(using will_paginate gem) where I have delete action(script call), I need to update pagination links on ajax success, I wanted to have ajax call for delete action so as to have filter options persists in page(filter records based on daterange and record type)

`<%= will_paginate collection, previous_label: "", next_label: "", page_links:false %>
<%= page_entries_info collection %>`

after the delete action I have replaced table body with records which aren't deleted, and I don't know how to change the pagination links(Modifying pagination link with previous page and displaying current page number with records in that page), I also reject the id of the record at will_paginate option and so as to prevent the get call for show action(when id gets added after delete and clicking on pagination links)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose your index will have pagination like this:

```
# app/helpers/paginations_helper
def my_pagination(collection)
  will_paginate(collection) + page_entries_info(collection)
end

# index.html.erb
# ...
<div id="my-pagination">
  <%= my_pagination @collection %>
</div>
```

After deleting with `remote: true`, Rails will call `destroy.js.erb`, so you can replace a new pagination:

```
# destroy.js.erb
$('#my-pagination').html('<%= j my_pagination(@collection) %>');
```

Comment: Won't this always lead to first page

Comment: On each delete path, you should to add extra params like this: `link_to 'Delete', my_path(@obj, page: params[:page]), method: :delete`

Comment: `collection = Model.filter(params[:search]).paginate(page: params[:page]) if params[:page]` I have added this in delete action to have the count of records at the current page, But it redirects to the first page of pagination

Comment: Did you add `remote: true` to your delete link?